# Master Page control in jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a Master Page and a Content Page(SomePage.aspx). The Content page has a control called Button1.

I am calling the Button1 using jQuery in MasterPage like this

```
$('[id$=Button1]').click(function() {
                        alert('');
                    });
```

However nothing happens. I have added MasterType in SomePage.aspx.

The Button is a linkbutton.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The code you've posted works, although [jQuery suggests](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEndsWith#attributevalue) `$("[id$='Button1']")` or `$('[id$=\'Button1\']')`.
The master page shouldn't be relevant here, it all goes to one HTML page at the end.
Make sure:

- The JavaScript is indeed on the page (no master page mistake) - view the source of the page and look for it.
- jQuery is loaded - try `alert(jQuery);` somewhere.
- Your jQuery code is inside [`$(document).ready`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready#fn)
- JavaScript is executed: very often a small JavaScript syntax error causes the whole page not to work. Try to debug it, or put some old-fashioned alert boxes before and after the code, to see how (and if) it runs.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed inputs..I have tried all these steps. The Button is a link button and calling $("[id$='Button1']").click(); has not effect. I added alert('') at load and it fired..however inside click nothing happens..

Comment: Try to add these alerts everywhere: before $(document).ready, inside it, before its end and after it. go nuts. Or, perhaps you can post the entire javascript block?

Comment: I observed one thing..It works with a button but not with a linkbutton

Comment: Asny idea why it does not work with LinkButton but works with a button? LinkButton looks like this <asp:LinkButton id="ttt" PostBackUrl="Hut.htm">Click</asp:LinkButton>

Comment: the LinkButton should be runat="server". Is it?

Comment: Well, no idea then, it worked for me. Could you post some more code? your JavaScript and generated link button (the <a ...> tag) would probably help.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be: '#[id$=Button1]'

Answer (score 1):

As Paolo mentions, be sure that it's in document.ready, as JS can't operate on an element that doesn't (yet) exist. Also, double-check your source to make sure the actual rendered ID of the control is as you expect.

You might find these controls helpful: http://clipperhouse.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the source code of your page as it is rendered by the browser and check the id of `Button1`. It is probably not `Button1` but something like `myContent$Button1`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar, I would like share with you some resources... hope can help :-)

http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2010/11/26/finding-controls-in-a-master-page-with-jquery.aspx